# How can I use backbone modal in my wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, backbone.js

I want when a manager click on details button in report page of my plugin, details are displayed inside a modal.
I want use built-in backbone.

when I load scripts like this, Its work but media page broken and not load!

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'userscore-soha', get_site_url() . '/wp-includes/js/underscore.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'backbone-soha', get_site_url() . '/wp-includes/js/backbone.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'backbone-modal', get_site_url() . '/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/admin/backbone.modal.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me quite a while to figure it out myself, but you were pretty close. This worked for me:

```
wp_enqueue_script(
   'backbone-modal',
   get_site_url() . '/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/admin/backbone-modal.js',
   array('jquery', 'wp-util', 'backbone')
);
```

You need to tell Wordpress to import jquery, wp-util and backbone.